# How to Compile Dlib in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, dlib

I am using Dlib for face landmark detection for my academic project.

When I am running Dlib 19.1 `webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp` file in Visual Studio 2010 c++ express, I wasn't able to get the results.

The steps followed

1. Created new project.
2. Added existing `webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp` and `source.cpp` file from `dlib\all` folder.
3. In VC++ directories added this path `D:\dlib-19.1\dlib-19.1` as Include Directories.
4. As `webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp` file uses `opencv/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp`, copied the folder from opencv 2.4.5 to `Dlib/opencv` folder.
5. Downloaded `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` file and mentioned the location.

**Question** I do not understand what I need to add as per screenshot. Because I have the video of .avi format.

[image]

**Note**: The only changes I have made in my code is instead of Webcam I have used saved videos.

The errors screenshot is added.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6LaU.png)

[image]

Comment: You don't know how to setup visual studio, so why don't you use cmake?

Comment: Have you considered getting a *modern* compiler? VS2010 is 6 years old and rather ancient - standard C++ wise..

Comment: modern DLib will not work with VS2010. try v18 . for v19.1 - use VS2015 update 3

Comment: @Davis King   Because of some problem I am not able to use Cmake..

Comment: @Evgeniy ya may be I can try this

Comment: @Lahiru ,Thank you so much.Its looking good and able to understand clearly.